# pytorch make_grid (from torchvision.utils import make_grid) behaves different then I expect

Tags: pytorch, visualization, torchvision

trying to run the *visualization utils* tutorial from **pytorch**, I tried it with some images of dogs found on the internet. the images used in the tutorial are not distributed for use.. making the gris and showing the result behaves funny - it shows each channel as a separate image (I guess this is what I see)

so -  from the tutorial

[image: from the tutorial:]

but here is what I get from the images I got:

[image: three sets of images instead of one]

I was expecting to see the two images in their original colors in a grid.

Another step I tried following Ivan's comment:

[image]

tutorial: https://pytorch.org/vision/master/auto_examples/plot_visualization_utils.html

I would like to know how to fix this (and use make_grid correctly)

Comment: FYI-- The images are in the torchvision github here: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/main/gallery/assets

Answer (score 2):

For the output you got, I would assume the correct shape is `(height, width, channels)` instead of `(channels, height, width)`. You can correct this with [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.permute.html#torch.Tensor.permute). The following should provide the desired result:

```
>>> grid = make_grid(torch.stack([transformed_dog1, transformed_dog2]).permute(0,3,1,2))
>>> show(grid)
```

Comment: thanks Ivan.  I tried exactly what you suggested and a slightly different version of it, attached below with the result (same result) - it did not work.  As I cannot add an image here - I added an image of the result in case I use your suggestion in the original question.